# Inconsistent number of pending edits on the new Facebook mini-site

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, mini-site

The number of suggested edits reported in the top bar is inconsistent with the number of edits actually in the queue on the new [facebook mini-site](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits).

[image: inconsistency!]

Comment: Weirdly, suggested edits are Facebook specific but flags aren't

Comment: my bad ... will have a think about this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This count will be correct after the next build, we'll pull and filter the tag sets correctly, the following will be included on sub-sites suggested edit screens:

- Questions with matching tags
- Answers of questions with matching tags
- Wiki excerpts & bodies of matching tags